# MFC image from array

Tags: c++, mfc, bitmap

What is the fastest/easiest way to convert an array (of double) into a MFC-Bitmap to be displayed in a Picture Control?

Comment: What is the bitmap supposed to look like? A picture? A diagram?

Comment: A picture - the array defines the color/greyvalue for a pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a `CMemDC`, where you can set every pixel by `CDC::SetPixel()`, and then BitBlt it over to a real CDC.

If you want a real bitmap, look here: [Creating HBITMAP from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598872/creating-hbitmap-from-memory-buffer)