# Display IPLimage/ MAT (opencv) in MFC picture box

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, mfc

I want to display an IPLimage / MAT (opencv) formats on a MFC picture box in Visual C++

Comment: Picture boxes can only display bitmaps I think. You'll need to convert IPLimage to a bitmap. Do it pixel by pixel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution describing how to display an IplImage in a MCF/C++ form application using OpenCV http://ac-it.pl/display-an-iplimage-in-a-mcfc-form-application-using-opencv

Answer (score 0):

Picture boxes can only display bitmaps I think. You'll need to convert IPLimage to a bitmap.

Assuming you can first convert IPLimage to a buffer of RGB values, see [Creating HBITMAP from memory buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4598872/492336)

Then when you get the HBITMAP, you'll need to load it in the Picture Box. Assuming by picture box you mean a static control, add `SS_BITMAP` to its styles, and then load the HBITMAP using

```
SendMessage(hStatic, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
```