# How to convert a char* to a Gdiplus bitmap in C++

Tags: c++, bitmap, char, gdi+

does anyone have an idea how to easily convert a char* to a Gdiplus::Bitmap in C++?

Background: I'm using the wkhtmltox library to generate a BMP from a website and I need to draw it on a Gdiplus::Graphics.

Thanks!

Comment: How about through the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: The accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598872/creating-hbitmap-from-memory-buffer should work, though it involves an extra copy to create the IStream.