# Convert vector <unsigned char> to HBITMAP in C++

Tags: c++, vector, hbitmap

I have used the code [here](http://lodev.org/lodepng/example_bmp2png.cpp) to load a PNG image into a BMP raw vector `std::vector <unsigned char>`. Now, I need to apply this image as background to a WinAPI window and I don't know how could I convert it to `HBITMAP`. Maybe somebody did it before or maybe I could use another format or variable type

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4598872/3747990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gdiplus from the start, to open png file and get `HBITMAP` handle

```
//initialize Gdiplus:
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

HBITMAP hbitmap;
HBRUSH hbrush;

Gdiplus::Bitmap *bmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"filename.png");
bmp->GetHBITMAP(0, &hbitmap);
hbrush = CreatePatternBrush(hbitmap);

//register classname and assign background brush
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
...
wcex.hbrBackground = hbrush;

CreateWindow...
```

Cleanup:

```
DeleteObject(hbrush);
DeleteObject(hbitmap);

delete bmp;

Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

You need to include "gdiplus.h" and link to "gdiplus.lib" library. The header files should be available by default.

In Visual Studio you can link to Gdiplus as follows:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "Gdiplus.lib")
```

---

Edit

or use `Gdiplus::Image` in `WM_PAINT`

```
Gdiplus::Image *image = Gdiplus::Image::FromFile(L"filename.png");
```

`WM_PAINT` in Window procedure:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    if (image)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
        g.DrawImage(image, Gdiplus::Rect(0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom));
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the size of the image to be the same as the window?

Comment: You can set background brush to zero, then paint in `WM_PAINT`, see edit. If you really need background brush then you have to resize image in `WM_SIZE`, use memory dc to resize image, etc. to create a new `HBITMAP`