# How to rasterize a vector image in C++ Win32 API

Tags: c++, vector-graphics, rasterizing, bresenham

recently I have been trying to experiment with vector graphics in C++. I want to make a Win32 app that reads an svg file and shows it on the screen. The program currently is simple. A window opens using the Win32 API and a .svg file is selected. This svg file's data is then converted to a struct data of my own. The conversion is good. The code of struct is as follows:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "Rect.h"

class VectorTexture
{
public:
    enum ShapeType
    {
        // Circle: x, y, r
        Circle,
        // Line: x1, y1, x2, y2, width
        Line,
        // Rectangle: x, y, width, height
        Rectangle,
        // Square: x, y, a
        Square,
        // Polygon: x[n], y[n]
        Polygon
    };

    struct Shape
    {
    public:
        ShapeType type;
        float data[];
    };

    Rect rect;
    std::vector<Shape> shapes;
};
```

Now, the next step is show the svg image. How can I rasterize the vector data that I have, to give me `HBITMAP` that I can show on the screen? If you know any resources, please put up a link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found two very interesting links redirecting to **"similar" issues** that might help you :

1. [Convert Vector Unsigned char to HBITMAP in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477145/convert-vector-unsigned-char-to-hbitmap-in-c)
2. [Creating HBITMAP from Memory Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598872/creating-hbitmap-from-memory-buffer)

Also have a look at
[GDI+ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-gdi-start).

Keep us in touch.

Comment: @ R. Theo thanks for the answer, the resource will prove really useful to me but if you or anyone knows how to rasterize the struct from the question, please help me!